# Reverse of a given string not passing test results,even though getting correct result in PHP

Tags: php

Reverse of a given string not passing test results,even though getting correct result in PHP.I am taking the user input using stdin,checking the user input is not numeric and printing the string in reverse format,but the code is not passing the test cases.

```
$fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   
$input = fgets($fr,128);        
$input = rtrim($input);     
if(!is_numeric($input))
{   
    $in=str_split($input);
    $s=sizeof($in);
    $final='';
    for($i=$s-1;$i>=0;$i--){
        $final=$final.$input[$i];
    }
    echo $final;
}
```

like below are the test cases,that the above code is giving wrong results,

```
1)First test case

5
a
aa
aaa
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ababababababa

2)Second test case

10
qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm
okrdx
abccba
apalskdalsfhad
asjdhaoeasnasnfkadbfasdas
alsdalsflaxncalljkdf
sdlfhsfsdfsdgs
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
asdfghjkllkjhgfdsa

3)Third test case

2
ab
aba
```

Comment: Any reason that you're not using [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)? There's also one that works with utf8 in the comments of that page.

Comment: Depending on the user input, this might be an encoding problem. Splitting a multibyte String with str_split can lead to strange results.

Comment: I tired strrev(),but even that did not pass the test results.

Comment: If its an encoding problem, try the multibyte split suggested in the PHP documentation comments: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#107658

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example; `$input`=? This works locally for me to reverse `asdf`.

Comment: Note that if you want to parse multiple lines, you should loop through them. Instead of $input = fgets.. you should do while ($input=fgets..) { ... }

Comment: Give one example with the input and the expected output. In all three examples you have numerical values so I never expect it to run through, `!is_numeric($input)`.